# ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm fascing several problems while trying to use the ng-select 1.4.1 in angular5 as in this [link](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select/#/data-sources),

This is the file .html :

```
 <ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
                         [items]="listClient | async"
                          bindLabel ="nom"
                          bindValue ="id"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId">

            </ng-select>
```

The first issue : the scrollBar in drop-down menu using ng-select is not dropping down , so i was adviced to use the pipe | async in : [items]="listClient | async" but i'm getting this error :

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError
```

and second Error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null
at AsyncPipe._dispose
```

any idea ?

Comment: How do you have `listClient` set up in your code? Is it an observable?

Comment: `listClient` is most probably a list of objects and not an Observable emitting the objects. The AsyncPipe expects to be passed an Observable. Can you share more code, i.e where you define `listClient`

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel it was not an observable that's why i got this error , it's resolved now thank you so much :)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes it wasn't an observable that's why i got this error , it's resolved now thanks to you comments :) !!

Comment: Can you add this as an answer and accept it then. thanks

Comment: Ofcours , can you please add your comment in an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: I'll let @DanielWStrimpel take this one seeing as his comment was the first

Comment: Okey , waiting for his answer :)